# C# MVC One to Many relationship with modelbuilder

Tags: c#, model, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys, relational-database

Hi I am creating  model in MVC that will be connected, the problem is when I do it on Modelbuilder it forces the relationship connection to the ID of the other table. what I'm trying to achieve is to just simply map my foreignkey to a different column in the other table

```
public class Table1{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string FK {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("FK")]
   public virtual DepartmentModel _table2{ get; set; }
}
public class table2{
   public int t2PK{get; set;}
   public string columnIWantToReferenceTo{get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Table1> _table1{get;set;}
}
//ModelBuilder
 modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>()
        .HasRequired(t1=> t1._table2).WithMany(t2=>t2._table1).HasForeignKey(t1=> t1.FK);
```

any help would be gladly be appreciated
thanks in advance!

Comment: [Great example](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: @Liran Already saw this and it doesn't answer my question if you refer to my table structure, I am basically joining on a different column, not on the primary key of table2 but rather a regular column(with unique values).

Comment: Because "columnIWantToReferenceTo" need to be in table 1 read the example I sent you before

Comment: assume that FK is the same as columnIWantToReferenceTo i just used it for clarifications